# iOS settings page helper class

Tags: ios, swift, class, uiswitch

I am trying to build a settings page helper class in order to simplify the setup of a settings page.

The idea would be that the class handles saving the state to UserDefaults and setting the initial state of any UISwitch.

Setting up a switch would just be a matter of setting a new switch to a class of "UISettingsSwitch" and adding the name of it to the accessibility label (it's the only identifier  available as far as i'm aware).

So far I have :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SettingsUISwitch: UISwitch {
    
    enum SettingsType {
        
        case darkMode, sound
        
    }
    
    func ison(type: SettingsType ) -> Bool {
        
        switch type {
    
        case .darkMode:
            
            return userDefaults.bool(forKey: "darkMode")
            
        case .sound:
            
            return userDefaults.bool(forKey: "sound")
        }
    
    }
    
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        initSwitch()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        
        initSwitch()
    }
    
    deinit {
    
    }
    
    func initSwitch() {
        
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggle), for: .valueChanged)
        
    }
    
    
    @objc func toggle(){
        
        userDefaults.setValue(self.isOn, forKey: self.accessibilityLabel!)
        
    }
}
```

Not an awful lot I know.

I can currently do :

```
 if settingsSwitch.ison(type: .darkMode) {
            
            print (settingsSwitch.ison(type: .darkMode))
            
            print ("ON")
            
        } else {
            
            print ("OFF")
        }
```

The accessibility label doesn't seem to be available in the init setup at any point, so setting up the initial state doesn't seem to be a possibility.
Is it possible to set the initial state of the UISwitch this way ?

Ideally , I'd like to expose : settingsSwitch.darkMode.ison as a boolean ... but I can't figure that one out. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use the restoration identifier to do the setup for the switch but I'd still love to remove the cases and the repeated calls to userDefaults

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class UISwitchSettings: UISwitch {
    
    enum SettingsType: String, CaseIterable {
        
        case darkMode = "darkMode"
        case sound = "sound"
        
    }
    
    func ison(type: SettingsType ) -> Bool {
        
        switch type {
    
        case .darkMode:
            
            return userDefaults.bool(forKey: "darkMode")
            
        case .sound:
            
            return userDefaults.bool(forKey: "sound")
        }
    
    }
    
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        initSwitch()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        
        initSwitch()
    }
    
    deinit {
    
    }
    
    func initSwitch() {
        
        if let key = self.restorationIdentifier {
            
            // Logic needs changing if default switch is off
            
            if userDefaults.bool(forKey: key) || userDefaults.object(forKey: key) == nil {
                
                self.isOn = true
                
            } else {
                
                self.isOn = false
                
            }
        }
        
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggle), for: .valueChanged)
    }
    
    @objc func toggle(){
        
        userDefaults.setValue(self.isOn, forKey: self.restorationIdentifier!)
    }
}
```